# Constructing arbitrary counterexamples to the converse of Lagrange’s theorem

Tags: group-theory

Given some $n$ and composite divisor $d|n$, is there a known way of constructing a group $G$ with $|G|=n$ with no subgroups of order $d$? Obviously this doesn’t work for all such $n$ and $d$, but is there a method of determining if this is possible for some $n$ and $d$ and making such a group?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33422/groups-with-order-divisible-by-d-and-no-element-of-order-d?rq=1).